# Sorting iterable values in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Let's say I have this input data:

```
["example.com", Date(2000, 1, 1)] : 100,
["example.com", Date(2000, 2, 1)]: 30,
["example.com", Date(2000, 3, 1)]: 5, 
["xyz.com", Date(2000, 1, 1)]: 20,
["xyz.com", Date(2000, 2, 1)]: 10,
["xyz.com", Date(2000, 3, 1)]: 60]
```

I want to group by the date (descending) and then sort by the count, giving me an ordered list of domains per date.

I want to end up with:

```
Date(2000, 1, 1), [["example.com", 100], ["xyz.com", 20]]
Date(2000, 2, 1), [["example.com", 30], ["xyz.com", 10]]
Date(2000, 3, 1), [["xyz.com", 60], ["example.com", 5]]
```

It seems like a normal use case but I can't see a way of doing this from the programming guide.

I can `map` `[[domain, date] count] -> [date, [domain, count]]`

which would give me `(K, V)` pairs

```
Date(2000, 1, 1), ["example.com", 100],
Date(2000, 2, 1), ["example.com", 30],
Date(2000, 3, 1), ["example.com", 5], 
Date(2000, 1, 1), ["xyz.com", 20],
Date(2000, 2, 1), ["xyz.com", 10],
Date(2000, 3, 1), ["xyz.com", 60]
```

then `groupByKey`, giving me `(K, Iterable<V>)` pairs

```
[Date(2000, 1, 1), [["example.com", 100], ["xyz.com", 20]]
[Date(2000, 2, 1), [["example.com", 30], ["xyz.com", 10]]
[Date(2000, 3, 1), [["example.com", 5], ["xyz.com", 60]]
```

How can I then sort within the keys?

Please excuse the pseudocode, I'm using the Flambo Clojure wrapper and I don't want to rewrite it in Java just to ask this question!

**EDIT:** Each Iterable (i.e. the list of domains) is probably going to be too large to fit in memory.

**EDIT2:** This is all psuedocode. I used month names to make this readable, but I've changed that to real dates for clarity.

Comment: They wouldn't fit in memory.

Answer (score 6):

In broad strokes, I would do the following. (May not be 100% correct since I didn't compile it, but close.) I will assume for simplicity you start with an `RDD[((String,String),Int)]`.

First, `groupBy` the month with something like:

```
.groupBy { case ((_, month), _) => month }
```

and get rid of month in the values:

```
.mapValues(_.map { case ((domain, _), count) => (domain, count) })
```

If ordering by month is desired, define the ordering of months:

```
def monthOfYear(month: String): Int = 
  month match {
     case "January" => 1
     case "February" => 2
     ...
  }
```

and sort the RDD by month:

```
.sortBy { case (month, _) => monthOfYear(month) }
```

and sort the domains by count descending:

```
.mapValues(_.toSeq.sortBy{ case (domain, count) => count }(Ordering[Int].reverse))
```

That's direct and efficient but has the problem that all domain-count pairs for a month must fit in memory.

Instead you could start over by sorting by count descending:

```
.sortBy(p => p._2, false)
```

and then group by month. I haven't tested this, and I don't think the behavior is guaranteed, but I expect that in practice the elements will be encountered in order by count even after grouping.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Like I said, I don't think the list of domains will fit in memory and I'd like to take advantage of Spark's facilities to do this. Also, I'm pretty close to 100% sure that the ordering isn't preserved during a group.

Comment: Oh also, the months are real (comparable) dates. I was just trying to illustrate.

Comment: OK, forget the part about dates. Hm, if your real end goal is simply top-N by count, you can do that without memory problems with `combineByKey`.